# It seems that Django forms.From is redundant compared with ModelForm?

Tags: django

when a programmer wants to generate forms in html and save data in database at same time, Django ModelForm is a better. Can anyone tell in which case, form is a better choice to use? Is there any jobs that only form can do instead of ModelForm? Can I only use the form to save data in database?

Comment: First example that comes to mind: the [`AuthenticationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) does not map to a model instance that must be saved to the database, and indeed, it's a `forms.Form` subclass, not a `forms.ModelForm` subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `ModelForm` is a type of `Form`, a sublass of it.
So `Form` is general while `ModelForm` is specific.

> Is there any jobs that only form can do instead of ModelForm?

If your form data doesn't map exactly into a model that you have, you may want to use `Form` and do the processing manually.

You may also subclass `Form`, e.g. `class MyCustomForm(Form)` to encapsulate some custom form mechanics that you need, and reuse your `MyCustomForm`.